# How to sort recyclerview data fetched from firebase by value in mvvm architecture

Tags: kotlin, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-mvvm

I am trying to sort datas which are fetched from firebase realtime database according to the value of a child using MVVM architecture the daabase reference is created in a repository

**GroupNoticeRepository**

```
class GroupNoticeRepository(private var groupSelected: String) {
    val auth = Firebase.auth
    val user = auth.currentUser!!.uid

    private val scheduleReference: DatabaseReference =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("group-notice").child(groupSelected)

    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: GroupNoticeRepository? = null
    fun getInstance(): GroupNoticeRepository {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {

            val instance = GroupNoticeRepository(groupSelected)
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance
        }
    }

    fun loadSchedules(allSchedules: MutableLiveData<List<GroupNoticeData>>) {

        scheduleReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                try {

                    val scheduleList: List<GroupNoticeData> =
                        snapshot.children.map { dataSnapshot ->

                            dataSnapshot.getValue(GroupNoticeData::class.java)!!

                        }
                    allSchedules.postValue(scheduleList)

                } catch (_: Exception) {

                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }


        })
    }
}
```

**GroupNoticeFragment**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    recycler = binding.taskList
    recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    adapter = GroupNoticeAdapter(_inflater)
    recycler.adapter = adapter
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[GroupNoticeViewModel::class.java]

    viewModel.initialize(groupId)

    viewModel.allSchedules.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        adapter!!.updateUserList(it)
    }

}
```

**GroupNoticeViewModel**

```
class GroupNoticeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var repository: GroupNoticeRepository
    private val _allSchedules = MutableLiveData<List<GroupNoticeData>>()
    val allSchedules: LiveData<List<GroupNoticeData>> = _allSchedules

    fun initialize(groupSelected: String) {
        repository = GroupNoticeRepository(groupSelected).getInstance()
        repository.loadSchedules(_allSchedules)
    }
}
```

`[image]

As you can see the current structure
group-notice
-groupId(groups)
-noticeId (notices)
- taskDate

Here under group notice there are some groups and in each group there are some notices(noticeId) .
Each notice has a task date . Now I am trying to sort the notices according to the taskdate meaning the taskDate which will is closer to todays date will view first in the recycler view. Or the notice with latest taskdate given will appear first in the recycler view .

Comment: Do you need an ascending or descending order? Are you allowed to change the value of a field? Ordering on the client is not the best option that you have.

Comment: I needed an ascending order. I am not allowed to change the value of the field . Well yes , ordering on the client side is not the best option . Can you provide me some details about the other ways !  As far as as I have seen in firebase the child are sorted lexographically by their key value . Is it possible to sort them according to one of their value ?

Comment: Yes, you can sort according to a value, but that value should change.

Comment: Would you mind referring to some article how this can be done and how the value should change !

Comment: You should get an ascending order when all children are generated using push(). Or you can convert the field from Sring to [timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74688251/how-do-you-deserialise-firestore-fieldvalues-in-android/74698782#74698782) and order accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as [hassan bazai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14279755/hassan-bazai) said I followed the same concept of comparing two dates

```
class FirebaseDataComparator : Comparator<GroupNoticeData?> {
    override fun compare(p0: GroupNoticeData?, p1: GroupNoticeData?): Int {

        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

        val firstDate: Date = dateFormat.parse(p0?.taskdate!!) as Date
        val secondDate: Date = dateFormat.parse(p1?.taskdate!!) as Date

        return firstDate.compareTo(secondDate)
    }
}
```

Here groupNoticeData is the data class I am using to populate the data in my recycler View and took two objects of them . Parsed their date format accordingly and later on compared them.
And in the recyclerViewAdapter before adding my data, I sorted them using the comparator class and added them later on. Here is the part where I had to use the comparator class.

```
fun updateNoticeList(notices: List<GroupNoticeData>) {
        Collections.sort(notices, FirebaseDataComparator())
        this.tasks.clear()
        this.tasks.addAll(notices)

        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
```